# Name collision. Two classes have the same XML type with uri and name

Tags: java, exception

I have an error when i try to integrate two webmethods:
Exception Description: Name collision.  Two classes have the XML type with uri http://xxx and name yyy.

The input of first webmethod is of type A. The input of second webmethod is of type B.

```
class C {
 string name;

 public string getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(string name) {
  this.name= name;
 }
}
```

```
class A extends C {
 C name;

 public C getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(C name) {
  this.name= name;
 }
}
```

```
class B extends C {
 C name;

 public C getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(C name) {
  this.name= name;
 }
}
```

(This is an example of my code; The classes are generated by an xsd)

How I fix this. Thank you for your help

I try to use

- @WebMethod (operationName = "operationA") for first method;
- @WebMethod (operationName = "operationB") for second method;

This is not fix the problem

Comment: Off-topic: Do you actually have a class or interface`string`, or did you intend to use `String`? Remember, Java is case sensitive.

Comment: Questions of this type should include, as text, a copy of the actual error message, and where it occurs /  what it points to. However, in this case, the example indicates a misunderstanding of basic inheritance. An instance of `C` already contains a `name` reference, and has `void setName (string)` and `string getName ()` methods. So, an instance of `C` has two variables called `name`.  One is a `string` (sic), the other is a `C`.